# Understanding/implementing this enumeration solution for maximum subarray

Tags: algorithm, python-2.6

[This is homework. I'm not asking for code-code, but I might need pseudocode to really grasp this.]

For my algorithms class, we're working on the maximum subarray problem. I've already implemented Kadane's linear solution, as well as the simple enumeration below:

```
def better_enumeration(Array):
    max_subset_sum = current_sum = 0
    start_subset_index = stop_subset_index =  0

    for i in range(0, len(Array)+1):
        for j in range(i, len(Array)+1):
            current_sum = sum(Array[i:j])
        
            if current_sum > max_subset_sum:
                max_subset_sum = current_sum
                start_subset_index = i
                stop_subset_index = j
    return (Array[start_subset_index:stop_subset_index], max_subset_sum)
```

Here are the specifications my professor has supplied:

> Algorithm 1: Enumeration. Loop over each pair of indices i, j and compute the sum ∑= []. Keep the best sum you have found so far.
>
> Algorithm 2: Better Enumeration. Notice that in the previous algorithm the same sum is computed many times. In particular, notice that ∑ = [] can be computed from ∑−1 = [] in O(1) time, rather than starting from scratch. Write a new version of the first algorithm that takes advantage of this observation.

At this point, I understand that once I have the sum of i:j, I can calculate i:j+1 much faster using the current_sum. The sticking points for me, I believe are:

- I'm not sure at which points I should start calculating current_sum -that is, i:j- and when I should be relying on current_sum to calculate i:j+1.
- How do I only calculate i:j sometimes, leaving i:j+1 to calculate most values?
- How do I prevent i:j+1 from overflowing a list of numbers?

UPDATE:

```
def better_enumeration(Array):
max_subset_sum = current_sum = 0
start_subset_index = stop_subset_index =  0

for i in range(0, len(Array)+1):
    current_sum = 0
    
    for j in range(i, len(Array)+1):
        current_sum += Array[j]
        
        if current_sum > max_subset_sum:
            max_subset_sum = current_sum
            start_subset_index = i
            stop_subset_index = j
            
return (Array[start_subset_index:stop_subset_index], max_subset_sum)
```

Now I just need to figure out how not to overflow the final iteration of j.

Comment: I suggest you refer to this [resource](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/). Also i'm sure if you try you'll be able to manipulate the code to retrieve the subarray with maximum contiguous sum.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Rahul. It looks like my implementation of Kadane's algorithm, which was easy for me to understand. I just don't really 'get' this improvement on enumeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we know that we can create a summation through the entire list. Summations have a base case though, this one is 0.

```
for i in range(0, len(Array)+1):
  current_sum = 0
```

So 0 goes in the outer loop.

```
for j in range(i, len(Array)+1):
  current_sum += Array[j]
```

The next thing you need to know is that the Python `range` function loops `range(x, y-1)`. We're overflowing the list here. If we don't overflow this list, then we still get an accurate summation, but we lose the last integer in the maximum subset.

```
  if current_sum > max_subset_sum:
    max_subset_sum = current_sum
    start_subset_index = i
    stop_subset_index = j
```

Once we understand how `range` works, a simple print loop through j, shows that we actually do encounter the full subset during the enumeration:

```
print 'Loop ' + str(j) + ': ' + str(Array[i:j])
```

Thus, our final issue is that `stop_subset_index` should equal `j+1`.